# Blackberry - Cant see always db in sd card emulator

Tags: database, sqlite, blackberry, emulation

I dont know what's happenning.

This is my code:

```
public class MyApp extends MainScreen {
Database sqliteDB;
URI uri;
String name;
public MyApp()
{
try{
uri = URI.create("file:///SDCard/Databases/sample/" +"prueba.db");

sqliteDB = DatabaseFactory.create(uri);
sqliteDB = DatabaseFactory.open(uri);
Statement st = sqliteDB.createStatement("CREATE TABLE joke(name)");
st.prepare();
st.execute();
st.close();

 Statement st1 = sqliteDB.createStatement("INSERT INTO joke VALUES ('Maxo')");
st1.prepare();
st1.execute();
st1.close();

Statement st2 = sqliteDB.createStatement("INSERT INTO joke VALUES ('Lala')");
st2.prepare();
st2.execute();
st2.close();

/*
Statement st1 = sqliteDB.createStatement("SELECT * from joke");



st1.prepare();
Cursor c = st1.getCursor();

Row r;
while(c.next()) {
    r = c.getRow();
     name =  r.getString(0);

}

st1.execute();
st1.close();*/
sqliteDB.close();


add(new RichTextField("Status: Database was created and inserted the values successfully"));

//add(new RichTextField(""+name));

}
catch (Exception e){
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

}
```

Im just creating a database, a table and inserting two fields. So what i do is first execute emulator, set a directory to my sdcard. Well after that i execute my program, and sometimes it creates the database in that directoy, sometimes not, sometimes it creates database without table or data.. i dont know why, i tried 8520 9550 emulator, but its rare whats happenning with database and sdcard. Anyone has an idea of what could be happenning? Its annoying to be coding and sometimes it works sometimes not and you dont know why.. And its not coding problem i think, because sometimes it works :S

Answer (score 1):

Make sure u have mounted your SD card.Double click on the folder where you want to save your database and then tick the checkbox for remounting it on next emulator run.

Hope it helps.

Comment: what checkbox are u talking about? i cant understand you. i just go to option Simulate - Change SD Card and then i select a directory. thats all im doing, i have to do anything more?

Comment: Change SD card -->Path to folder on add directory(U'll see a green arrow on adding)-->Below theres a check box next to HELP CLOSE buttons.Check tick that.It'll work properly.And on next emulator run,before opening ur app icon check the sd card whether its REmounted.

Comment: im sorry maybe i didnt tell u that im developing on eclipse platform. i think u are telling me how to do this in jde blackberry. Its so rare man, i dont know whats happenning really

Comment: yup bud this was for bb jde...i am unsure how it works with eclipse IDE.Though i'd always recommend BB JDE for development as its much intuitive and easier.